# Laravel Http-only cookie

Tags: php, authentication, vuejs3, laravel-9

I have a small project using Laravel and Vue.js. I implemented a simple authentication system using Sanctum, based on YouTube tutorials and the official documentation. It works correctly; however, I am concerned about storing the JWT on the client-side using local storage, as I believe it is not a secure way to handle authentication tokens. While searching on Google, I came across the "http-only" approach. How can I implement this in Laravel 9.52? I noticed that many tutorials are for older versions of Laravel and do not work for me :(

Comment: Have you checked whether the cookie is already flagged as HTTP-only? I think that's been the [default](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bcd25bd1e261068aed48836d2796333f3a313aa5/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.php#L64) for Laravel for a while now.

Comment: JWT = JSON Web Token _(there are already too many abbreviation in programming)_. A token is usually something that a client needs to store somewhere, local storage is as good a place as any. The security should come from Laravel Sanctum. Or, to put it in another way: Why do you think that storing the token in local storage is not secure? When it comes to security you shouldn't go by a gut feeling, you should actually understand what's going on.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I understand your point of view, and security should come (Also) from the backend like limit and expiration time etc... but I must point out that this is not a feeling but facts. At all times there are session and xss thefts with authentication tokens. I even had this curiosity to improve the security of tokens because a developer friend had this problem too. However, this link has some additional details: https://medium.com/kanlanc/heres-why-storing-jwt-in-local-storage-is-a-great-mistake-df01dad90f9e

and in a practical test of a security expert: https://youtu.be/WX4BHSm9uPI

Comment: The danger that unwanted scripts can read the token from the local storage is certainly true ([XSS attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)). Cookies on the other hand are vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf). Most systems that use tokens therefore have protection mechanisms against stolen tokens. I'm not sure Laravel Sanctum has those mechanisms, and it might not be the right tool for the job.

Comment: You can protect your site somewhat against CSRF attacks by using the [SameSite attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) of a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Sanctum has two ways to authenticate users, through Laravel's built-in cookie based session or API Token in an Authorization header.

If you uses the cookie then you have nothing more to do.

If you uses the token you need to store it somewhere on the client side, you have (basically) two options : localstorage or cookie.
But Sanctum is only looking for it inside the Authorization header, so you need to retrieve it (storage/cookie) before inserting it in the request header. So your cookie can't be http-only...

An other solution could be to send it in a http-only cookie and get sanctum to retrieve it by creating your own callback for `Laravel\Sanctum\Guard::getTokenFromRequest()` by adding this in the boot method of your AppServiceProvider :

```
Sanctum::getAccessTokenFromRequestUsing(function($request) {
    return $request->cookie('your_cookie_token_name');
});
```